# Breezejs: create entities from junction table in many to many relationship

Tags: breeze

I have a many to many relationship between 2 tables (Entity1 and Entity2), with a junction table (JunctionEntity).
In Breeze client, I want to:

1. Create an object of type Entity1, e1
2. Link e1 to one or more objects of type Entity2 that already exist. To do that, I create instances of JunctionEntity, j1 and j2.
3. Savechanges

To do that, I create e1 using manager.createEntity, and use also manager.createEntity to create j1 and j2. I just set, in these objects, the properties: Entity1Id and Entity2Id.

Problem: I see in the console that these entities are passed from the browser to the server. But when debugging on the server, e1's JunctionEntity list is null.

Should you need more information about this problem, please let me know.
I feel I must be doing a conceptual mistake.

Thanks for your help

Nicolas

Comment: @kadumel, please read the question. I do use a junction entity. The objets I am trying to create are instances of the junction entity.

Comment: So e1 uses a many to many relationship of junction objects as does e2.  Each relationship still has a many to many relationship to the junction entity.  Sorry what am I missing again?

Comment: Sorry, it's not like that. Entity1 has a many-to-many relationship with Entity2, through the JunctionEntity. Of course, that means that Entity2 and Entity2 both have a one-to-many relationship with JunctionEntity, that's how it works...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was too impatient, as often...
I was encountering this problem that my junctionentity list was null, which is actually normal!
All I had to do was let the code run a little longer, to see that the entities from the function table get correctly saved afterwards. They are sent from the client to the server, but as separate entities, which makes perfect sense.

Patience is the mother of all virtues, when will I ever learn that one? :)